# Is this an excerpt of a police report by Floyd Mayweather's son?

Tags: law-enforcement

A claim has been circulating on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/mmaencyclopedia/status/594163334808608768) with an attached image:

> Dear Boxing Fans: This is the guy you are supporting tomorrow, from
>   the hand of his young son. #MayweatherPacquiao

[image: Photo in question]

I'm not asking whether the allegations described in the report is genuine ([very plausible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd_Mayweather,_Jr.#Criminal_convictions)). I'm wondering whether the excerpt of the report is genuine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that this document is perfectly genuine. It was reported by USA Today in 2014 but today the  testimonials from the son went viral, the police report is split into 5 parts:

- [Temporary Restraining Order](http://i.usatoday.net/sports/Investigations-and-enterprise/Mayweather-Documents_Part1.pdf)
- [Incident report](http://i.usatoday.net/sports/Investigations-and-enterprise/Mayweather-Documents_Part2.pdf)
- [Koraun Mayweather's (Floyd Meriweather's son) testimonial](http://i.usatoday.net/sports/Investigations-and-enterprise/Mayweather-Documents_Part4.pdf)
- [Josie Lynn Harris's testimonial](http://i.usatoday.net/sports/Investigations-and-enterprise/Mayweather-Documents_Part5.pdf)

This is the second part of the son's testimonial:

[image]

This is the first part of the mother's testimonial:

[image]

This is the first part of the temporary restraining order:

[image]

Incident report:

[image]

Read the rest of the full detailed story on [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/boxing/2014/11/18/floyd-mayweather-josie-harris-domestic-abuse/19221605/).